# Cant use a return value from another function/python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

I am new to python-ish and trying to user the value held in the server variable that is returned at the bottom of select_target_server_type in another program. The first set of code is my menu.py and its just an input/decision tree.

My second code is rest_engine.py which calls menu.start_program() and that works great but when I want to retrieve the value of a function in one of the menu functions I cant get it to work it seems.

```
def start_program():
    select_target_server_type()


def select_target_server_type():
    # SUPPORTED SERVERS FOR API CALLS
    # DISPLAYS A LIST TO USER TO CHOOSE FROM

    print("\nWelcome!\nThese are the supported systems, please select a value by entering the corresponding "
          "numbered value\n")

    while True:
        try:
            print("1. APIC-EM")
            print("2. ISE")
            print("3. CSR")
            print("4. Quit")
            server = int(input("\nPlease select a SYSTEM TYPE to continue:   "))

            if 0 >= server or server >= 5:
                print("\n***Incorrect Selection***\n\n")
                pass
            else:
                break

        except Exception as e:
            print("\n\n***oops***")
            sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        try:
            if server == 1:
                print("\nYou have selected APIC-EM \n")
                api_top_menu()
            elif server == 2:
                print("\nYou have selected ISE \n")
                api_top_menu()
            elif server == 3:
                print("\nYou have selected CSR \n")
                api_top_menu()
            elif server == 4:
                print("\nQUITTING APPLICATION\n")
                sys.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            print("\n\n***oops***")
            sys.exit(1)
        return server
```

Second program rest_engine.py (calls the first)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests
import menu


menu.start_program()

name = menu.select_target_server_type()
print(name)
```

Functioning Code Output:

```
> /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/danield/PycharmProjects/YODA/rest_engine.py
> 
> Welcome! These are the supported systems, please select a value by
> entering the corresponding numbered value
> 
> 1. APIC-EM
> 2. ISE
> 3. CSR
> 4. Quit
> 
> Please select a SYSTEM TYPE to continue:   1
> 
> You have selected APIC-EM 
> 
> 1. GET
> 2. PUT
> 3. DELETE
> 4. quit Please select a function to continue:   1
> 
> You chose to use GET
> 
> 1. INVENTORY
> 2. NETWORK DISCOVERY
> 3. TBD
> 4. Quit Please select the FUNCTION category:   1
> 
> You chose Inventory
> 
> 
> 
> ***oops***
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you verified you're actually hitting that return statement and that it's non-null?

Comment: When I learned c# I knew how to step through a program but with python I havent figured out how to do that. I am unsure how to verify that.

Comment: Not sure if it's directly related to your problem, but it would be useful to print more information than just "oops" when an exception occurs. Or just let the errors go uncaught so you get the full diagnostic information during the crash. How can you debug problems without a stack trace or error message?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem:

Post all your code! We cannot see the code that displays the other lists (i.e. the function and FUNCTION) lists. How can we help with a partial problem? Update your post!

`menu.start_program()` is called, and in `menu.py` it calls `select_target_server_type()` within it. However, `select_target_server_type()` is set to `return server`, so it will `return sever` to the calling function `start_program()`. However, the `start_program()` function isn't coded to receive a `return` from its function call to `select_target_server_type()`. However, before it can even `return server` an error is being caught somewhere. But we cant see `api_top_menu()` so we can't help you there unless you update your post.

Try these changes:

**rest_engine.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests
import menu

name = menu.start_program()

print (name)
```

**menu.py**

```
def start_program():
    server = select_target_server_type()


def select_target_server_type():
    # SUPPORTED SERVERS FOR API CALLS
    # DISPLAYS A LIST TO USER TO CHOOSE FROM

    print("\nWelcome!\nThese are the supported systems, please select a value by entering the corresponding "
          "numbered value\n")

    while True:
        try:
            print("1. APIC-EM")
            print("2. ISE")
            print("3. CSR")
            print("4. Quit")
            server = int(input("\nPlease select a SYSTEM TYPE to continue:   "))

            if 0 >= server or server >= 5:
                print("\n***Incorrect Selection***\n\n")
                pass
            else:
                break

        except Exception as e:
            print("\n\n***oops***")
            sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        try:
            if server == 1:
                print("\nYou have selected APIC-EM \n")
                api_top_menu() # we need to see this code too!
            elif server == 2:
                print("\nYou have selected ISE \n")
                api_top_menu()
            elif server == 3:
                print("\nYou have selected CSR \n")
                api_top_menu()
            elif server == 4:
                print("\nQUITTING APPLICATION\n")
                sys.exit(0)
            return server # will end the infinite try here
        except Exception as e:
            print("\n\n***oops***")
            sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First, seems like not all of those things need to be in while loops, but that's a separate issue. Second, when you do menu.start_program(), you're running your function select_target_server_type, but you don't store the return value. You only try to store the return value when you call the whole thing again: name = menu.select_target_server_type()

But you never get to that line (with name=...), because the first call, to start_program, terminates the running process.

Third, your program is running into an error and thus terminating via the sys.exit(1) line, so the function never gets the chance to return anything.